# Find grouped values and then concatenate rows

Tags: sql, algorithm, vba, ms-access

I am having trouble writing a query or queries that will get the results that I want.

Basically, I am trying to find unique "companies." The problem is that some companies own multiple businesses operating at the same address. I'd like to concatenate those values, while not duplicating the results of 1 company operating at 2 addresses.

Sample data:

```
Company  Address
A        1
A        2
B        1
C        3
```

So we have unique `companies`:

```
A
B
C
```

and `addresses`

```
1
2
3
```

I'd like to get two records for the results:

```
A, B
C
```

(So ideally, in the first table, the results for A-1, A-2, and B-1 would all have point to the same autonumber in a different field.)

Comment: Please try to show the query you have written so far.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify:

- A business can have multiple addresses
- Any business in a **business group** (AKA company) shares an address with any other business in the group
- A business group can own multiple businesses
- Each business is only associated with one business group (corollary to second point)

[SqlFiddle with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae6f1/1)

---

We can refer to each business group by the first (smallest name in alphabetical order) business in the group. Let's call this the **key business**. After we've identified the key business for each business, we can group by the key business and get the results.

In order to get the key business:

- Generate a list of pairs of businesses where both businesses are in the same group, based on any shared address. This list should exclude the following (see next point for why):

  1. `A -> B`, when we have `B -> A`
  2. `A -> A`

  The left side of the pairs should be unique: each business should appear on the left side of the pair no more than once, if at all.
- For each business, follow the pairs from one to the next until the right business is never the left business in any other pair. That is the key business.

  That is the reason for the exclusions in the first point. If we have both `A -> B` and `B -> A`, we'll get to a never-ending loop. Same goes for `A -> A`.

---

The first part can be done straightforwardly in pure SQL:

```
SELECT Businesses.Business AS Business2, MIN(Businesses_1.Business) AS Business1
FROM Businesses
INNER JOIN Businesses AS Businesses_1 ON Businesses.Address = Businesses_1.Address
WHERE Businesses.Business > Businesses_1.Business
GROUP BY Businesses.Business
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae6f1/3)

---

(Other RDBMS support [recursive joining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_join), so for the second part we could start with the source data and direct the database to keep joining indefinitely until the final `Business1` is `NULL`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32029604/111794). AFAIK MS Access doesn't support this in SQL, so we'll have to do it in VBA.)

I suggest using `Scripting.Dictionary` for this purpose. You'll need to add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** (**Tools -> References...**).

```
'Create a Dictionary to hold the pairs
Dim pairs As New Scripting.Dictionary

'Load the pairs using the above SQL
Dim sql = _
    "SELECT Businesses.Business AS Business2, MIN(Businesses_1.Business) AS Business1 " & _
    "FROM Businesses " & _
    "INNER JOIN Businesses AS Businesses_1 ON Businesses.Address = Businesses_1.Address " & _
    "WHERE Businesses.Business > Businesses_1.Business " & _
    "GROUP BY Businesses.Business"
Dim rsPairs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenForwardOnly)
Do Until rsPairs.EOF
    pairs(rsPairs!Business2) = rsPairs!Business1
Loop
rsPairs.Close
Set rsPairs = Nothing

'Create a Dictionary to hold the groupings
Dim groupings As New Scripting.Dictionary

sql = _
    "SELECT DISTINCT Business " & _
    "FROM Businesses " & _
    "ORDER BY Business"        
Dim rsBusinesses As DAO.Recordset
Set rsBusinesses = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet(sql, dbOpenForwardOnly)
Do Until rsBusinesses.EOF
    Dim business As String
    business = rsBusinesses!Business
    If Not pairs.Exists(business) Then
        Dim col As New Collection
        col.Add(business)
        groupings(business) = col
    Else
        'Find the group's key business
        Dim prevBusiness As String
        prevBusiness = business
        Do While pairs.Exists(prevBusiness)
            prevBusiness = pairs(prevBusiness)
        Loop
        groupings(prevBusiness).Add(business)
    End If
Loop
```

The final Dictionary will look like this:

```
Key    Collection
A      (A, B, W, X)
C      (C)
D      (D, E, F, G)
```

and can be iterated over as follows:

```
Dim key As Variant, item As Variant
For Each key In groupings
    Debug.Print "Grouping " & key
    For Each item In groupings(key)
        Debug.Print "Business - " & item
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I'v updated my answer and reflected more on the business problem and the similarities between the SQL and dictionary approaches. I can see that the dictionary approach handles a hierarchy (using a nice technique I've learnt from - I've not used dictionaries before, but have used hierarchical SQL).  I can't see where the hierarchy might be in the data.  Can you help.  I'm pretty certain your approach is the best method, but I am trying to learn more about this myself.  I think the main issue is the  OP business problem has not really be thoroughly documented.

Comment: I have opened a new SO question based on the problem outlined in this one. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011157/using-sql-server-to-process-data-representing-relationships-between-a-web-of-obj)

Comment: @HarveyFrench I've reworked this answer so the intention is at the beginning. This also works better when describing the recursive join approach in my answer to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding your question!
Please confirm my interpretation then consider my answer

You have this Example data in tableBA

```
BUSINESS  Address   < notice I call this BUSINESS not company
A        1
A        2
B        1
C        3
D        4          < I have added four businesses sharing the same address
E        4
F        4
G        4
X        5          < X does not share an address with any other businesses
X        6            but it does operate at multiple addresses
```

You really need to clarify how you would want the above cases to be handled.

Some companies own multiple businesses operating at the same address.  I have assumed that there may be cases where more than two businesses share the address, although this is not the case in your example data.

1. Where no other businesses are  operating ANY OF the addresses used by a business, we can use the business name as the company name. (As in C above).  Note that A is operating alone in address 2, but because it shares an address with B it must not be included.
2. Where many business operate at the same address use all their business names as the company name by concatenating them together (comma separated).

Each of the "company names" created above should only be listed once ie like this

```
A, B
C
```

MY ANSWER

Ordering the above data by address then business name:

```
Data       Resulting text wanted
1, A       A, B
1, B

2, A       NONE

3, C       C

4, D       D,E,F,G
4, E
4, F    
4, G

5, X      X
6, X
```

---

The following situation might arise, what to do then?   ie P shares two different addresses with two other companies

```
7, O   
7, P

8, P
b, Q
```

---

Part 1. to get "C" and "X"

```
SELECT Tab1.address, Tab1.Business
FROM tableBA AS Tab1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tableBA AS Tab2
    WHERE Tab2.Business <>  Tab1.Business
      AND Tab2.Address IN (SELECT Address 
                             FROM  tableBA AS Tab3
                            WHERE tab3.Business = Tab1.Business)
    )      
GROUP BY Tab1.Business
```

The EXISTS clause only returns true if the business in Tab1 does not have other businesses at any of it's addresses.

---

Part 2. to get "A, B" and "D,E,F,G"

```
SELECT Address, Business
FROM tableBA
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT Address
    FROM tableBA
    GROUP BY Address
    HAVING COUNT (*)>1
    ) As Tab1       
    ON tableBA.Address = Tab1.Address
```

The subquery only returns address used by more than one business and limits the rows returned.

You now need to "pivot" the results so that you only have one line per address with all the business names as columns.

There are various ways you might do this with code and I would probably use a recordset to open the above part 2 query and loop through all it rows appending to a string.

---

Using the results of part 1 & 2

Where the resulting list of strings is stored is another matter, it sounds like you want to write it to to a table for later use.

I would base the recordset mentioned in part 2 on the queries in part 1 and part 2 unioned together.

ie

```
SELECT ... ie the part 1 query 
UNION 
SELECT ... ie the part 2 query
```

an process all rows together, probably inserting the resulting list into a table.

Personally, I find this method be more straight forwards that using a dictionary object, as it allows you to use SQL to view the records that are being processed and created.

Comment: Yes it will.  Which is why you then need to process the resulting recordset, to "pivot" it as described.